# Order between dependent objects with Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am reading data from a RestfulAPI which represent dependent entities.
e.g from /students I get student objects and from /teachers I get teacher object. 
Student is connected to Teacher object (student has teacher Id).
The problem is that I produce from /students to Kafka into students topic and from /teachers to teachers topic but when I try to join between them with Kafka Streams, sometimes the event of student comes before its teacher event has arrived thus I do not receive the joined record of student and teacher (due to early arrived students).
To use window is not optimal because I would like to get student updates all the time.

1. My question is - how do I sync the events so I'll be able to resolve depending objects.
2. Currently I'm polling the API service manually and produce the results to Kafka - is there any way to use Kafka Connect instead with the Rest API as a source in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should help:

1. Create a stream for the Teachers topics, since incoming records will be stable.
2. To handle an incoming flow of students, create a `KTable` for Students.
3. Perform an non-windowed join between teachers and students.

`KTable` is a changelog stream, so all incoming records will be treated as inserts or updates.

You can refer to [this documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#overview).